# Determine which implementation is applicable?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

We have an interface in our Springboot 2 code that references an abstract method on interface of type MessageChannel  (org.springframework.messaging)

The implementation is in a class that is autoconfigured and pulled in by maven as a transitive dependency, likely by a maven artifact for RabbitMQ

In Intellij, I click the down arrow in the gutter and see a dropdown containing 33 implementations.

How can I tell which implementation in the dropdown is the one that applicable?

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot simply debug your code and see which implementation ends up being used at runtime?

Comment: Also, you should get a small green bean icon in the gutter next to the autowired field. If you click it, it will take you to the location where the candidates for autowiring are being created. I'm talking about IntelliJ Enterprise, of course

Comment: I have Intellij Ultimate but when clicking the green bean it says no autowired candidates.  Just expecting that geen bean to be better help when the implementation is in a jar that was pulled in by the pom.  I wanted to see if I could find the implementation without having to run the code